# Parallel Arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need to store the minimum points in a 1D integer array named intPoints.

- Store the grades in a 1D String array named strGrades.
- The arrays should be parallel arrays.
- The Display button's  Click event procedure should search the intPoints array for the number of points entered by the user.
- It then should display the corresponding grade from the strGrades array.

---

```vb
Public Class frmMain
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPoints_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPoints.Enter
        txtPoints.SelectAll()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPoints_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPoints.KeyPress
        ' accepts only numbers and the Backspace key

        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPoints_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPoints.TextChanged
        lblGrade.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        'Declare and Initialize Arrays

        Dim intPoints As Integer = {0, 300, 350, 400, 450}
        Dim StrGrades As String = {"F", "D", "C", "B", "A"}
        Dim subscript As Integer
        Dim subscript2 As Integer
        Dim searchFor As Integer

        subscript2 = 0
        searchFor = Integer.Parse(txtPoints.Text)

        For subscript = 0 To intPoints.Length - 1
            If searchFor <= intPoints(subscript) Then
                subscript2 = subscript - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If subscript2 = 0 Then
            subscript2 = intPoints.Length
        End If

        lblGrade.Text = StrGrades(subscript2).ToString()

    End Sub
End Class
```

This is what i have now, before i'd put in the numbers and "A" would be the only letter that would come up for every grade, and now i have errors for intPoints and strGrades. Some feedback would greatly be appreciated

Comment: just a question about your logic: if you score, lets say, 1 point do you want the user to get a grade of F or D then? Anyway: you forgot to declare the intPoints and Grades as arrays. Use () behind the Typ.

Comment: I want them to get an F if they score 1 point

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) for this kind of scenarios; following code works fine for me and give expected output;

```
        Dim gradePoints As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) ' declaration of dictionary
       'Adding values to the dictionary
        gradePoints.Add(0, "F") 
        gradePoints.Add(100, "E")
        gradePoints.Add(200, "D")
        gradePoints.Add(300, "C")
        gradePoints.Add(400, "B")
        gradePoints.Add(500, "A")
        Dim searchKey As Integer = 200 'defining point to be searched
        MsgBox(gradePoints(searchKey)) 'Print the grade corresponds to the point
```

**The output will be "D"**

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think your code even compile.

```
' You are setting intPoints as a single integer but you initialize it as an array
Dim intPoints As Integer = {0, 300, 350, 400, 450}
```

You should learn to use break point and step through your project. Lets look at what happens if the number of point is 0.

```
    For subscript = 0 To intPoints.Length - 1
        ' The first item of the array is 0, the if will be true
        If searchFor <= intPoints(subscript) Then
            ' subscript2 will be equal to -1
            subscript2 = subscript - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ...

    ' Crash! Since subscript2 is equal to -1
    lblGrade.Text = StrGrades(subscript2).ToString()
```

Let's try if the point is 100

```
    For subscript = 0 To intPoints.Length - 1
        ' The second item of the array will work
        If searchFor <= intPoints(subscript) Then
            ' subscript2 will be equal to 0 (subscript = 1)
            subscript2 = subscript - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' Since subscript2 = 0, you'll change it to 5
    If subscript2 = 0 Then
        subscript2 = intPoints.Length
    End If

    ' Crash! Since the array goes from 0 to 4
    lblGrade.Text = StrGrades(subscript2).ToString()
```

You are doing to much stuff. You just need to keep the position where the point was found and display that letter. This assume that 450 is the highest score.

```
    searchFor = Integer.Parse(txtPoints.Text)

    For subscript = 0 To intPoints.Length - 1
        If searchFor <= intPoints(subscript) Then
            subscript2 = subscript
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    lblGrade.Text = StrGrades(subscript2).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

First: you need to declare your intPoints and StrGrade as arrays.
Do this by adding () behind the Typ.
like this:

```
  Dim intPoints As Integer() = {0, 300, 350, 400, 450}
  Dim StrGrades As String() = {"F", "D", "C", "B", "A"}
```

Then there is some logic bug in your code: if `points <= intPoint(i)` and `points = 1` then the user would score a "D" because 1>0 but 1<=300.

Here would be my Solution to the problem, it walks backward thorough the array, hoping that the students scored high^^

```
 Sub calculateGrade()
        Dim input As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtPoints.Text)
        Dim intPoints As Integer() = {0, 300, 350, 400, 450}
        Dim StrGrades As String() = {"F", "D", "C", "B", "A"}

        'go through the full array, lenght is one bigger than the biggest Index so substract it
        For i As Integer = 0 To intPoints.Length - 1
            'move backward through the array
            If (input >= intPoints(intPoints.Length - 1 - i)) Then
                'if he hits the limit, give him the grade and exit the loop
             lblGrade.Text = StrGrades(i).ToString
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: sorry for the delay, I wrote it at Friday, but it seams i didn't send the answer